# Get record with true in a column, otherwise another record

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fk_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `is_main` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

With these rows:

| id | fk_id | is_main | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **1** | **0** | **first_name** |
| **2** | **2** | **1** | **second_name** |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | third_name |
| **4** | **3** | **1** | **4th_name** |
| **5** | **4** | **1** | **5th_name** |

I need to get rows for `fk_id` with `is_main = 1`. But, if for some fk_id there are no rows with is_main = 1, I need to get another row (also random, whatever) for the same fk_id:

Right now I am using standard `where` to get rows with is_main = 1:

```
SELECT fk_id, name FROM my_table WHERE is_main = 1 AND fk_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

With this query, I do not get any rows for fk_id = 1.
Instead I need to get rows with `id = 1, 2, 4, 5`

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. (And tables have _rows_, not records.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use row_number() to basically first select all the records for your fk criteria, then from this selection, take the first from each group. We are partitioning by `fk_id` and ordering by `is_main desc`, so if there is an `is_main` record for the group, it will be selected as the first record in the group, otherwise you will get another record where `is_main` is false.

Sql is written for SQL Server - adjust as needed for MySql etc.

```
create table #temp (
    id int, fk_id int, is_main bit, [name] varchar(30))
insert into #temp (id, fk_id, is_main, [name])
values 
    (1,     1,  0,  'first_name'),
    (2,     2,  1,  'second_name'),
    (3,     3,  0,  'third_name'),
    (4,     3,  1,  '4th_name'),
    (5,     4,  1,  '5th_name')

select T.fk_id, T.[name]
from 
(
select 
    fk_id,
    [name],
    is_main,
    row_number() over (partition by fk_id order by is_main desc) as seq
from #Temp
where 
    fk_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
) T
where t.seq = 1;
```

Results:

| fk_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first_name |
| 2 | second_name |
| 3 | 4th_name |
| 4 | 5th_name |